# python - form check doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem. I want to create a form in python. If something is wrong, I want an alert-window (`showwarning()`). Otherwise it should write 'TRUE' into the command line.
The problem is that I get every time a alert-window. It does not care if the form is filled out correctly or wrong.
Can somebody help me with this problem?

code:

```
""" Variables """

    inputError_1 = bool(0)
    inputError_2 = bool(0)
    inputError_3 = bool(0)
    valueCheck = bool(0)

""" Check-Button """
def Check():
    if len(nameOne.get()) == 0:
        inputError_1 == TRUE
    elif len(nameTwo.get()) == 0:
        inputError_2 == TRUE
    elif len(comment.get(INSERT)) == 0:
        inputError_3 == TRUE
    else:
        valueCheck = bool(1)

    if inputError_1 == FALSE or inputError_2 == FALSE or inputError_3 == FALSE:
        showwarning()
    else:
        print'TRUE'
```

Comment: `inputError_1 == TRUE` is a statement that yields `True`, but have no other effects. You mixed up equality comparison `==` and assignment `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do this in a simpler way:

```
def check():
    if len(nameOne.get()) == 0 or len(nameTwo.get()) == 0 or len(comment.get(INSERT)) == 0:
        showwarning()
    else:
        print 'True'

check()
```

Comment: You can safely replace `len(nameOne.get()) == 0` with `not nameOne.get()` here. It could read better.